# How to prevent a kernel module from opening a specific device?

Tags: usb, kernel-modules, modprobe

I am using two devices, one of which requires usbserial for proper operation (a GPS, using gpsd; [this guide](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/faq.html#verify) specifies that usbserial is required), and one of which requires usbserial to be unloaded (the FTDI FT232H; [this guide](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt) specifies that `rmmod usbserial` must be run to use the D2XX drivers).

Is there some way that I can instead add rules to prevent usbserial from touching the FTDI device, while still allowing gpsd to use usbserial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *unbind* interface in sysfs. Please refer to [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) for details. You will find instructions for automating the unbind upon discovery of the device in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947392) answer.